# Change type after pivoting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot, casting

The following code results in a DataFrame df, but `df.plot()` is not working.

- Before pivoting, `Value` is type integer.
- After pivoting, `Value` is type object.

I tried:  `df.reset_index()`, but this failed to cast the object values back to integer type.

How can I plot this DataFrame?

```
def changeDateFormat(row) :
    item=row['Datum']
    return item.strftime("%Y%W")


#initialize list of lists
data =  [[355, '2022-04-01','1'],
        [289,'2022-04-15','2'],
        [144, '2022-05-01','1'],
        [213, '2022-05-03','2'],
        [333, '2022-05-06','2']]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Value', 'Datum','Line'])
df['Datum']= pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])
df['WK']=df.apply (lambda row: changeDateFormat(row), axis=1)
df=df.pivot_table(index=["WK"], columns=["Line"],values = 'Value' 
,fill_value="",aggfunc='mean')
```

Comment: Could you share sample data that works with your code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If you add df.plot() to the code above you get the error

Answer (score 0):

you when you did your pivot you have this now :

```
df['1'].values
array([355.0, '', 144.0, ''], dtype=object)
```

As you can see '' will transform the column type into an object. What you can do it is to replace '' by a flag value : NaN or -999 or 0 and change the type of you columns into a int for example